# String std::logic_error: basic_string::_S_construct null not valid

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string S = 0; 
    int T,R;
    
    cin >> S >> R;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < S.length(); k++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < R; j++)
            {
                cout << S[k];
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The error pool statement is:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
   what(): basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
```

Comment: Funny that you would try to initialize a `std::string` to 0 when it isn't necessary but not initialize the other variables where it is good practice. Since `T` is uninitialized and never assigned it's probably not the best thing to use as your loop limit.

Answer (score 5):

`string S = 0;` is interpreted as `std::string S{nullptr};` which is [forbidden](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

Just write `string S;` instead.

Comment: And the next problem is that `T` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 4):

After you fix the hard error of `string S = 0;`, you also have undefined behaviour, as you use `T` without initialising it.

Also `using namespace std;` pulls in far too many names, [you shouldn't do it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10077).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string S; 
    int R;
    
    std::cin >> S >> R;
    
    for(int i = 0, T = 1/*???*/; i < T; i++)
    {
        for(char c : S)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < R; j++)
            {
                std::cout << c;
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```